# Customized Affixed "Back to Top" Link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I love this [back to top](http://jsfiddle.net/panman8201/mkzrm/10/) link that Panman came up with. Is there a way of styling this through CSS? .... Is there a way to turn it from a square button to circle shape?

```
#top-link-block.affix-top {
position: absolute; /* allows it to "slide" up into view */
bottom: -82px; /* negative of the offset - height of link element */
left: 10px; /* padding from the left side of the window */
}
#top-link-block.affix {
position: fixed; /* keeps it on the bottom once in view */
bottom: 18px; /* height of link element */
left: 10px; /* padding from the left side of the window */
}
```

This is the CSS code provided, I can't seem to do much to style it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
#top-link-block a{
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome and You can accept this as answer if it solved your problem. Thanks:)  (Green tick mark)